# Archive files in a folder by year

Tags: file-system, powershell

I created a code to archive files in a folder by year. It writes subs of the root folder into an array, then writes the sub of those subs into an array, runs through each folder and then archives the files in each folder by the last edited year.

```
$Grade    
$StartYear = 2001;
$EndYear = 2021;

$Grade = @(Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot |
             Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
             ForEach-Object {$_.Name})


For ($Counter1=0;$Counter1 -lt $Thickness.Count;$Counter1++){
    
    $Thickness = @(Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\$($Grade[$Counter1]) |
                 Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
                 ForEach-Object {$_.Name})

    for($Counter2=0;$Counter2 -lt $Thickness.Count;$Counter2++){
        $Path2 = "$PSScriptRoot\$($Grade[$Counter1])\$($Thickness[$Counter2])";
        if(!(Test-Path -Path "$Path2\Previous Years")){
               new-Item -Path "$Path2\Previous Years" -ItemType Directory
        }
        for ($year = $startYear; $year -le $endYear; $year++){
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Path2 -Filter "*.WS" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $year } | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$PSScriptRoot\$($Thickness[$Counter2])\Previous Years\$year.zip"
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Path2 -Filter "*.WS" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $year } | Remove-Item
        }   
    }
}
```

What I want to know is whether there is any way to make this code run better.  I'm new to Powershell so I don't know what looks like bad code or good code.

Comment: The title should state what the app does, not what you want reviewed. Thanks.

Comment: Was `#Get-ChildItem -Path $Path2 -Filter "*.WS" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $year } | Remove-Item` supposed to be commented out like this? Did you want to make this part of the script optional perhaps?

Comment: Was not supposed to be a comment, fixed it on my side. Will edit question and change.